# Angular 2 textbox delay

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

The issue is this: I have a large form, which is basically a grid of text boxes. The actual grid has 23 columns and up to 400 rows. This grid is generated dynamically using an ngFor and a FormArray as the number of records is arbitrary.

When you go to type in the text boxes, there is a huge lag before the text changes.

Is there a way to speed this up without having less text boxes?

here is a plunkr to demonstrate this:

```
    <div  class="row" *ngFor="let fg of slowFormArray.controls; let i = index">    
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
    <div class="col" ><input type="text" value="1"  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"  (keyup)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown)="fastKeyDown($event)"  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (input)="$event.preventDefault()" (change)="$event.preventDefault()"/></div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/seLHqs36lAZiykdGHbXP?p=preview

Be sure to use Chrome

Make sure you detach the view window, so you can see many textboxes at once.

Comment: You wouldn't want to load them all in the dom you'd need to create something similar to virtual scroll to only display the in view rows.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/823#issuecomment-333805921